# Wix: How to get the return status of a custom action and use it as a condition to run certain event/show dialog

Tags: wix, wix3.5

May i know how to get the return status of a custom action (that is running a command line) and use it as a condition to run certain event/show dialog? For example, in a dialog, when i click on the next button, it runs a custom action. Then, if the custom action run suceessfully, go to the next dialog. Otherwise, show the dialog with error message. Does anyone have any idea or example codes that i can refer to?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use some property, and assign some value based on the result of custom action and use this property to go to next dialog or show error message.

Answer (score 1):

I guess MSI does not support what you want.
You can either instruct it to fail if .exe had non-zero exit code or to ignore it. If you want the exit code, write a DLL custom action which will start the .exe and get its exit code. Then you'll be able to set a property in MSI session and use it in condition.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what vinay has said:

A great article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43564/WiX-Tricks#_Toc245109720

The last part of the article gives you a good guidance on passing parameters around.

```
String propertyValue = session["PROPERTYNAME"]; //gets a property value from wix file
session["PROPERTYNAME"] = propertyValue; //sets a property value that can be used in wix file
```